# Firebase Test Lab - iOS app not being installed

Tags: ios, firebase, xcuitest, firebase-test-lab

I am new to Firebase Test Lab, and I'm having issues running my XCUITests against an iOS app. I have had success running Espresso tests against an Android APK on Test Lab, and have even successfully ran tests against an iOS app that I found on GitHub. (https://github.com/Shashikant86/Scalable-XCUItest) However, it seems that there is something in the app that I'm testing that prevents it from being installed on the Test Lab physical device.

This is not a personal project so the amount of information that I can share is very limited, but I'll share whatever I can from the logs that might be of use without sharing any private information:

`HTTP load failed (error code: -1001 [4:-2104])`

`load failed with error Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1001 "The request timed out."`

`load failed with error Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1003 "A server with the specified hostname could not be found."`

Log from Firebase is in this Gist: https://gist.github.com/ChiWhiteSox56/b6122f4ccd488a3fb0dcfe53aa45e2af

Clearly there's something happening around the app's ability to reach the required server but as I mentioned earlier, I've been able to run the tests successfully against other apps.

Thanks for reading, and if any additional information is required to troubleshoot this issue, I'll try to provide as much as I can.

Comment: This seems to be a very specific issue with your app, but the logs you posted don't really tell what's going on. The best would be to join the [Firebase Slack Community](https://firebase.community/) and to post your issue + the test matrix id in the [#test-lab](https://firebase-community.slack.com/messages/C1MTSQ5QT/) channel. This will allow the team to further investigate.

Comment: Thank you. I suspected that I might not have provided enough information here, but I am limited as far as what I can share. I joined the FTL Slack group, and if I can find a resolution to my issue I'll update this post for others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After joining the Firebase Slack Community and posting this question, I received a twofold response from the FTL (Firebase Test Lab) team.

1) The provisioning profile for the app that I'm testing includes an app group entitlement. App groups are currently unsupported by FTL because they do not have permission to re-sign apps with an app group. Provisioning profiles that may re-sign multiple apps may not have the app group entitlement.

Note: FTL can run tests for apps with an app group entitlement if the app can function without the group. FTL will strip the entitlement, so this does not require any action on the part of the app submitter.

2) As I mentioned above, I was only able to share limited logs from my project. After the FTL team looked into the full logs from my test run, they determined that the issue that I was experiencing was not, in fact, related to the app group issue. It was an unrelated issue, and a bug has been filed to address it.